# How can I solve $\sin(x)=\sin(2x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Solve $\sin(x)=\sin(2x)$

How do I solve this equation for $x$ without a calculator?

It seems pretty simple but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Clue: $\sin (2x)=2\sin (x)\cos (x)$

Answer (score 9):

Recall a trig identity:

$$\sin 2x = 2 \sin x \cos x$$

So your equation can be factored:

$$\sin x = \sin 2x \implies 2 \sin x \cos x - \sin x = 0 \implies \sin x (2 \cos x - 1) = 0$$

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively $\sin{2x}=\sin{x}\iff 2x=(-1)^nx+n\pi$

So $x=2n\pi$ or $x=\dfrac{(2n+1)\pi}{3}$

Comment: This is much more generic & universal

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to make a whole new answer for this; I don't have sufficient permissions for comments (yet).

I just want to clear up something; (and also to clarify trb456's comment). T. Bonger included this:

$\sin x=\sin 2x$

$⟹ 2\sin x\cos x− \sin x=0$

$⟹ \sin x(2\cos x−1)=0$

It seems to me that where steps are condensed is where you're getting confused.

The second one has two steps in one; $sin 2x$ is replaced by $2 sin x cos x$ *and* the $sin x$ is subtracted from both sides *and* the left and right sides of the equation are flipped.

So, to expand that:

$\sin x = \sin 2x$

$⟹\sin x = 2\sin x \cos x$

$⟹0=2\sin x \cos x-sinx$

$⟹\sin x(2\cos x−1)=0$

$⟹\sin x = 0$  $\text{or}$ $ (2\cos x - 1) = 0$

Good Luck!