# Trigonometric equation $\cos (5x) = \sin (x)$ - How to find $5x$?

Tags: trigonometry

I want to find the general solution of the following equation for $x \in \mathbb{R}$:

> $$\cos (5x) = \sin (x)$$

I know it might sound silly, but I don't know how to bring $5x$.

Comment: See if http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/643217/how-can-i-solve-sinx-sin2x inspires you.

Answer (score 6):

HINT:
$$\cos(5x)=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-5x)\\\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-5x)=\sin x$$

Comment: OMG how could I not see that! Beatifull (+1)

Comment: your'e just awesome

Answer (score 3):

$cos5x=cos(\pi/2-x)$ so this implies $5x=\pi/2-x+k2\pi$, or $5x=-(\pi/2-x)+k2\pi$. Now you can solve for $x$ (and thus $5x$)

Comment: Slightly better than kingW3's almost simultaneous answer with the same approach, as the eveness of cosine makes it easier to express the two angles in each period with matching cosines.

Answer (score 1):

using the Addition formulas we obtain $$\sin(5x)=16\,\sin \left( x \right)  \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{4}-
12\,\sin \left( x \right)  \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}+
\sin \left( x \right) 
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\cos 5x = \sin x$$

$$\sin 90^°- 5x = \sin x$$

$\sin a= \sin b$ then $a=n\pi + (-1)^nb $ where $n∈N$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\cos 5x = \cos ^5(x)-10 \sin ^2(x) \cos ^3(x)+5 \sin ^4(x) \cos (x)
$$

[image: trigs]

One solution $$x = \pm \frac{\pi}{4}$$